# Forum to discuss deep learning ideas

Tags: applications

Is anyone aware of an idea exchange for ai/deep learning/data science?  I occasionally have ideas that don't relate to my focus areas that I would love to discuss with those who might like to hear them. (Not that they have any value, just don't like ideas to die in my head)

Sorry if this isn't appropriate in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of "open science" labs that focus on machine learning. Most of them operate on Discord. You can go on there to discuss ideas, talk about papers, and get publishing help.

The most famous is probably EleutherAI and ML Collective. There's also "open research" style communities that have a specific focus like OpenBioML, LAION, CarperAI, Harmonai R&D, RWKV (all taken from the EleutherAI #communities channel, you can also find invite links there).

Comment: Thank you!  I am an older engineer in a specialized and highly specific field, so I don't get exposed to as much of the larger community as others in more competitive fields do.  But, my brain never shuts off and may occasionally generate ideas someone could use that I will never have the time to explore.. :)